# asp.net MVC Redirect to another view (with parameters) after process of another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-ajax

Good day to all.
I created an ajax process to process and validate the records.
If success, need to call the controller action with parameters to be forwarded to another view. If without parameter (TeamStructureConfirmation), the controller is being called but whenever i put a parameter, it doesn't seems to work.

What seems to be the problem?
Here is the code:

Script

```
$('#btnConfirm').click(function () {
    var parentPositionID = @ViewBag.ParentPositionID;
    var yearID = @ViewBag.YearID;
    var yearCycleID = @ViewBag.YearCycleID;
    var userID = $('#txtUserID').val();
    console.log('user id => ' + userID);

    $.ajax({
        url: "ReviewedAndApproved",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: { ParentPositionID:parseInt(parentPositionID), YearID:parseInt(yearID), 
            YearCycleID:parseInt(yearCycleID), UserID:userID },
        error: function () {
            OpenAlertWindow("Review and approve failed!");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Status == "Success") {
                approvedConfirmation({ParentPositionID:parseInt(parentPositionID), YearID:parseInt(yearID), 
                    YearCycleID:parseInt(yearCycleID), ProcessStatus:data.ProcessStatus});
            }
            else {
                OpenAlertWindow(data.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    });        
});

function approvedConfirmation(e)
{
    console.log("here in approvedConfirmation");
    $.ajax({
        url: "TeamStructureConfirmation",
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        contentType: "html",
        data: { ParentPositionID:parseInt(e.parentPositionID)},
        //data: { ParentPositionID:parseInt(e.parentPositionID), YearID:parseInt(e.yearID), 
        //    YearCycleID:parseInt(e.yearCycleID), ProcessStatus:e.ProcessStatus },
        error: function () {
            OpenAlertWindow("Confirmation failed!");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //window.location ="ConfirmedTeamStructure";
            //if (data.Status == "Success") {
            //    toastr.success('Success', 'Your Team Structure has been reviewed and approved!');
            //}
            //else {
            //    OpenAlertWindow(data.ErrorMessage);
            //}
        }
    });
}
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult ReviewedAndApproved(long ParentPositionID, long YearID, long YearCycleID, string UserID)
    {
        string strStat = string.Empty;
        string strError = string.Empty;
        string strProcessStatus = "ProcessStat.Incomplete";
        string strUserID = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

        if (strUserID == UserID)
        {
            var positionAssMngr = new PositionAssignmentManager();
            var dtoList = new List<PositionAssignmentDto>();
            string ActionTaken = "Reviewed and Approved";

            dtoList = positionAssMngr.GetTeamStuctureMembers(ParentPositionID, YearID, YearCycleID);

            if (positionAssMngr.ReviewedAndApprove(dtoList, ActionTaken) == true)
            {
                strStat = "Success";
                strProcessStatus = "CompletE";
            }
            else
            {
                strStat = "Failed";
                strError = "Approved and Reviewed process failed!"; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strStat = "Failed";
            strError = "User ID not matched with current user!";
        }

        return Json(new { Status = strStat, ErrorMessage = strError, ProcessStatus = strProcessStatus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public ActionResult TeamStructureConfirmation(long ParentPositionID)
    {
        var model = new List<PositionAssignmentDto>();
        //var posMngr = new PositionAssignmentManager();

        //if (ProcessStatus == "CompletE")
        //    ViewBag.Validated = true;
        //else
        //    ViewBag.Validated = false;

        //model = posMngr.GetTeamStuctureMembers(ParentPositionID, YearID, YearCycleID);
        return View("Team/ConfirmedTeamStructure", model); 
    }
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Unclear what your wanting to do. What is `approvedConfirmation()`? And are you trying to redirect to the `TeamStructureConfirmation()` method if the value of `data.Status` is `"Success"`?

Comment: The approvedConfirmation has been truncated.
Yes i need to redirect to the TeamStructureConfirmation method after the data.status is success.

Here is the snippet for approvedConfirmation

Comment: ajax calls never redirect (the whole purpose is to stay on the same page). If you want to redirect, then just use `if (data.Status == "Success") { location.href = '@Url.Action{"TeamStructureConfirmation", new { ParentPositionID = ViewBag.ParentPositionID }); }` And there is no need for all that `parseInt()` in your scripts (every thing is just sent as text)

Comment: Thank you StephenMuecke. I'll try your suggestion then feedback on the result. I appreciate your effort and response.

Comment: It works Sir StephenMuecke.